# SQL min function

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, min

I am trying to get two columns, `frequency` and `frequency - min(frequency)` but all I see is zero for the second column. What could possibly be wrong?

```
SELECT
    frequency, frequency - min(frequency)
    FROM
    words
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY frequency;
```

[image]

Comment: Please show some sample data. The data you show seems fine: 1-1 = 0, 5-5 = 0. I'm sure that's not what you mean...

Comment: Are you using [tag:mysql] or [tag:postgresql]? Those are two very different databases.

Comment: I need minimum frequency of entire table.  I guess it is considering min frequency of just that row

Comment: @Mureinik ... edited the tags.. using postgresql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query groups by the unique value of frequency. In each such group, the minimal frequency is just the frequency itself, so you always get `0` when subtracting the two. Instead, you could use the windowing version of `min`:

```
SELECT   frequency, frequency - MIN(frequency) OVER() AS diff
FROM     words
ORDER BY frequency
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a sub-query that returns the min frequency value:

```
SELECT
    frequency, frequency - (select min(frequency) from words)
    FROM
    words
ORDER BY frequency;
```

**Edit:**

Wrap it up in a derived table:

```
SELECT frequency, frequency - minfreq, frequency + minfreq
FROM words
    CROSS JOIN (select min(frequency) minfreq from words) dt
ORDER BY frequency
```

Comment: Ah... can we name the (select min(frequency) from words) and use it over and over again instead of writing the sub query?

Comment: SELECT
    frequency, frequency - minfreq, frequency + minfreq
    FROM
    words
    where minfreq = (select min(frequency) from words)
ORDER BY frequency;

Is this even possible?

Comment: `SELECT frequency, frequency - minfreq, frequency + minfreq FROM words, (select min(frequency) minfreq from words) t  ORDER BY frequency`

Comment: Added alternative, like splash58 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
SELECT frequency, frequency-min_frequency
FROM ( 
SELECT frequency,  MIN(frequency) AS min_frequency 
FROM words
GROUP BY frequency
) as A 
ORDER BY frequency;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a queer query. You group by ID, so you get one result record per ID. But ID suggests that this is the table's ID identifying records uniquely. So `GROUP BY id` doesn't change anything, you still get all records in your results. With one exception: `min(frequency)` now means the minimum frequency per group. As the "group" is one record, the minimum value is the the value itself of course. The non-aggregated `frequency` is also the records' frequency uniquely identified by ID. So your query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT
  frequency, frequency - frequency
FROM words
ORDER BY frequency;
```

I suppose you want to compare each record's frequency with the minimum frequency found in the table? You'd get this value in a subquery:

```
SELECT
  frequency, frequency - (select min(frequency) from words)
FROM words
ORDER BY frequency;
```

Or:

```
SELECT
  w.frequency, w.frequency - m.min_frequncy
FROM words w
CROSS JOIN (select min(frequency) as min_frequncy from words) m
ORDER BY frequency;
```